# XSL:FO transformation in Altova XMLSpy

Tags: xsl-fo, xmlspy, altova

I mapped Altova XMLSpy to Apache FOP for XSL:FO tranformation(Tools->Options->XSL->Selected fop.bat),then I wrote a simple HelloWorld output as below and tried to tranform the XSL:FO to a PDF output,But XMLSpy threw this error " Temporary file could not be created!Access is denied" , Can someone tell me why I get this error and how to resolve it?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

              <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="hello"
                page-height="11in"  page-width="8.5in" margin-top="1in" 
                margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in">
                  <fo:region-body margin-top="1in" margin-bottom=".5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
              </fo:layout-master-set>

              <fo:page-sequence master-reference="hello">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                  <fo:block font-size="18pt" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                    Hello World!
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
              </fo:page-sequence>

            </fo:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Altova site](http://www.altova.com/support_faq_ide_browser.html) mentions:

> This is a problem with IE. When you open an XML file straight from an
>   e-mail the file is saved in a temporary folder. XMLSpy® 2012 can
>   handle this and successfully save and therefore show an XML file. IE
>   on the other hand cannot successfully do this and gives an "Access
>   Denied" message. Saving the file first will enable IE to show it
>   correctly.

Could this be your problem? It definitely is something related to Altova XMLSpy, not to your specific XML or XSL.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted some html into a new, unsaved Xmlspy html document.  I then switched from Text view to Browser view.  Xmlspy showed an error "temporary file could not be created", "access denied".  When I ran procmon, it turns out that Xmlspy was trying to create the file as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Altova\XMLSpy2013\tmp0000.html".  As I am running Windows 8, all of the files and directories under "C:\Program files (x86)" require elevated privileges to be created / updated / deleted.

It is an Xmlspy defect.  They need to create their temp files in the correct location.  I guess if you really needed it to work, you could run Xmlspy with elevated privileges.  I don't need it that badly.